# Unable to access network files from ASP application even after granting permissions

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10

I have a network folder `\\myserver\c$\my folder` that I want to be able to read files within from an ASP.NET Blazor app, which is running on a server in an Active Directory domain.  I have done the following:

- I created an Active Directory user `MyUser` and granted it permissions to `\\myserver\c$\my folder`
- In IIS Manager, I created a new Application Pool **MyAppPool**.  In the Advanced Settings, I set **Identity** to `mydomain\MyUser` and set **Load User Profile** to **true**
- In IIS Manager > [My Server] > Sites > [My Site] > Advanced Settings, I set the **Application Pool** to **MyAppPool**.

I checked Task Manager > Details, and `w3wp.exe` is running as `MyUser`

However, when I try to access the file with `File.Copy` in C#, I get the error `Access to the path '\\myserver\c$\my folder\my file.txt' is denied.`

What else do I need to do to allow my ASP application to access files in that directory?

Comment: Is the MyUser account in the Administrators group of the server to connect to C$ I think it might have to be....OR create a normal share on the file server that MyUser can get to.

Comment: Blazor Server or Blazor on Web Assembly?

Comment: @LexLi Blazor Server.

Comment: @NickAbbot MyUser is not in the administrators group.  Let me try creating a normal share.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @NickAbbot Thank you, your solution worked.  I created a share as `\\myserver\my folder`, and now it works.

Comment: `c$` is called an administrative share, which is a default share of the root of the C drive that is created by the system. The dollar sign ($) at the end of the share name means that the share is hidden, and it won't show up when you list the shares on a machine. Administrative shares are usually restricted to administrators. Since you found the solution, you can accept your own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (as one of the comments points out) was to share `c:\my folder` on **myserver** as `\\myserver\my folder` and access my file as `\\mysever\my folder\my file.txt` instead of `\\myserver\c$\my folder\my file.txt`